# JavaScript: Decode a PHP json_encode response

Tags: javascript, php, json

For example, I am `json_encoding` my array and outputting it:

```
$key = $this->key;
                    $sql = "SELECT * FROM Requests";                   
                    $result = $this->db->query($sql);
                    $temp = array();
                    foreach($result as $r)
                    {
                        if($r['key'] == $key){
                        array_push($temp, array(
                            'song' => $r['song'],
                            'artist' => $r['artist'],
                            'by' => $r['by']
                        ));
                        }
                    }
                    $this->encoded = json_encode($temp);
                    echo $this->encoded;
```

Then, I am sending a `GET` request to it:

```
$.get('http://www.example.com/file.php')
                .done(function(data){
                    alert(data['artist']);
                });
```

However, this alerts:

> undefined

Can anyone possibly help me? I've searched a lot and tried a lot but nothing seems to be working (like, `JSON.Parse`).

Edit: I tried adding the `header('Content-Type: application/json');` but it leaves me with this error:

> TypeError: data is null

Thanks in advance!

```js
$.get('http://www.syncsapi.x10host.com/API/Public/', {
  start: 'example'
})
$.get('http://www.syncsapi.x10host.com/API/Public/', {
    display: '5'
  })
  .done(function(data) {
    console.log(data[0]);
  });
});
```

```html
<meta content="text/html;charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
<meta content="utf-8" http-equiv="encoding">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Returning JSON from a PHP Script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4064444/returning-json-from-a-php-script)

Comment: that returns: `TypeError: data is null` now

Comment: Can you share the exact output of that php script?

Comment: that is the exact output, but when i `echo "test";` it works because `data` is set as "test" :/ just, when i echo the `json_encoded` or `array`, the `data` is undefined or null

Comment: `console.log(data)`, see what it even _is_

Comment: No the output of your PHP script, as your webserver emits it. Not the output of your javascript.

Comment: its " " - I already did this but if I `echo "test";` when i log data, its test

Comment: @dandavis: fairly sure it's going to say `null` ;)

Comment: [{"param":"args"}] @Evert

Comment: @Evert: i'm sure it's not, or else `alert(data['param'])` would throw instead of showing `undefined`

Comment: Ok that's a problem Kyle. Your object is wrapped in an array. The PHP script you're sharing is not the complete PHP script.

Comment: This is the issue with sharing code samples that are not representative of your actual problem. What you're sharing here should just work, but your real code is different enough for it to break.

Comment: Second then, this is it: ill edit

Comment: So next  time you ask a question, it's still a good idea to simplify your code for stack overflow, but make sure you test to see if you can reproduce the issue with the simplified code sample.

Comment: this outputs: [{"song":"Body Bag Season","artist":"Don Dyno","by":"Kyle"}]

Comment: it has no `param` ... but, `alert(data[0].song)`

Comment: K adding my answer now ;)

Comment: thanks @Evert - sorry about that, just hate sticking database code into shared places x)

Comment: Actually, also share your js code to reproduce this real problem. Because it doesn't match the php anymore. There's no `param`

Comment: ya sorry, thats actually 'artist' @Evert

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So the problem with your script is that you are basically emitting something like this:

```
[
  {
    "song"   : "...",
    "artist" : "..."
  }
]
```

But your javascript code is expecting something like this:

```
{
  "song"   : "...",
  "artist" : "..."
}
```

If your intention was to only ever send back one song for that PHP service, you should modify your PHP service to remove the top-level array.

However, if you intend to send back more than 1 song, then the data you returned makes sense, but your javascript does not. To fix your javascript, you could simply change:

```
alert(data['artist']);
```

into:

```
alert(data[0].artist);
```

Note that `.artist` and `['artist']` is the same, the real difference in my sample is that I added `[0]` which grabs the first item in the top-level array.

Comment: with the header mentioned below: error - `TypeError: data is null` without it: error - `data[0] is undefined` :/

Comment: @KyleE4K I'm thinking then there might still be something wrong with your php script. Is it possible at all to send the url so I can take a look?

Comment: `$.get('http://www.syncsapi.x10host.com/API/Public/', { display: '5' })
                .done(function(data){
                    
                    console.log(data[0]);
                    alert(data[0].artist);
                });`

Comment: Awesome. Interestingly your PHP script emits nothing! Empty string.

Comment: Verify by just opening http://www.syncsapi.x10host.com/API/Public/?display=5 in a browser.

Comment: I did, i changed it to a string but im changing it back to the array now. (note that i am cross domain referencing using cors - I am just really bad with JavaScript)

Comment: if you run http://syncsapi.x10host.com/API/Public/?display=5 i browser now, you'll get the result @Evert

Comment: Still nothing @KyleE4K

Comment: I am receiving this: `[{"song":"Body Bag Season","artist":"Don Dyno","by":"Kyle"}]` when i directly access that link through browser, if you're doing so by code, you have to send a request before which integrates your `key`, use example

Comment: I don't. Also not when trying it on the command line with curl: `curl -v http://syncsapi.x10host.com/API/Public/?display=5` yields nothing and 'Content-Length: 0`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106525/discussion-between-evert-and-kyle-e4k).